# Credit issue calculation

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am having issue with Calculation in NodeJs, not sure where did I go wrong.

There are GiftCard balance and it should calculate how much credit you have used for an order (`CreditUsed`) and how left you to need to pay `(PayRemaining`).

For example:

```js
const order = {
    DeliveryCost: 5,
    ItemPrice: 5,
    OrderTotal: 10,
}

const giftCredit = {
    Balance: 50
}

function calculate(order, giftCredit) {
    const remainingPay = Math.max(0, order.OrderTotal - giftCredit.Balance);

    const creditBalanceRemaining =   giftCredit.Balance - order.OrderTotal;
    const usedCredit = giftCredit.Balance - creditBalanceRemaining;

    return {
        CreditUsed: usedCredit, 
        PayRemaining: remainingPay
    }
}

console.log(calculate(order, giftCredit));
```

This have returned correctly:

```
{ "CreditUsed": 10, "PayRemaining": 0 }
```

However, if I change the giftCredit Blance to 3, it is not returning correct CreditUsed:

```
{ "CreditUsed": 10, "PayRemaining": 7 }
```

I am expecting CreditUsed to be 3.

Where did it go wrong and how would you fix it?

Comment: Hey it's returning correct figure. If you use Balance = 3, CreditUsed will be in 10

Comment: How can you use more credit from the gift card than what it started out with? If the gift card balance started with 3, how can you have used 10 from it?

Comment: I was just telling u the out put. If you want the correct formule, I can answer that

Comment: I just did @I'll-Be-Back check it out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we just need to consider that if our order is greater than or equal to our balance, it means we've used all our credit balance, and if not we can deduct the remaining balance from the original balance and get our answer

```
function calculate(order, giftCredit) {
    const remainingPay = Math.max(0, order.OrderTotal - giftCredit.Balance);

    const creditBalanceRemaining =  giftCredit.Balance - order.OrderTotal;
    let usedCredit = giftCredit.Balance;
    if (creditBalanceRemaining > 0) {
        usedCredit = giftCredit.Balance - creditBalanceRemaining;
}
    return {
        CreditUsed: usedCredit, 
        PayRemaining: remainingPay
    }
}
```

I just checked if only it's greater than 0 and assigned the balance to our used vat to avoid another else statement.

Answer (score 0):

The usedCredit const variable will equal 10 because the calculation being set to it is: 3 - -7 = 10